# minidump error message With A lots of layer (shp file)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I'm newbie in GIS or QGIS. I want to create mapweb, Map has a lot of layers (shp files) about 40 layers. I used QGIS2web to create map web. When I add some layers, it was no problem, but when I tried to add all of my layers, I got error minidump error.

What should I do?

Comment: Which QGIS and qgis2web versions are you using and what is the typical size of your shapefiles? This information might help potential answerers :)

Comment: I used QGIS 2.8.2. But I have solve my problem for this time. Thank you :) @Joseph

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have found the mistake was not because the number of layers (shp file), but because the name of an attribute in some layers was improperly used (has space between words). This time, I can create webmap using QGIS2WEB.